# How to evaluate the convolution of y[n]=3^nu[-n+3]*u[n-2]?

Tags: convolution

What steps do I need to do in order to solve this convolution? Having a bit of trouble here.
$y[n]=3^nu[-n+3]*u[n-2]$

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE. To I recommend you to use MathJax for future post. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. Also, it would be much better and helpful for everyone if you share what you have thought of and what you have accomplished in this problem. Thank you!

Comment: And how should we figure out what $u$ means here? You should give more context.